# Performing MATCH/INDEX on large dataset

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, vlookup

I have a dataset of 55.000 rows with 35.000 email-addresses of which 31.000 are unique, so a couple of users occupy multiple rows. I need to find the rows of these users and add them to a class object.

Loading the email column into an array and performing a MATCH/INDEX lookup took 200 seconds. It's acceptable for now, but definitely not fast enough for it's intended use of 200-500K datasets.

```
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer

Dim dict As Dictionary
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set UserRange = Range(Cells(2, 11), Cells(LastRow, 11))
For Each cell In UserRange
    dict(cell.value) = dict(cell.value) + 1
Next

Debug.Print "Number of users: " & dict.Count

UserArray = Range(Cells(2, 11), Cells(LastRow, 11))
UserArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(UserArray)))

For Each User In dict
    Dim UserIndex() As Variant
    ReDim UserIndex(1 To dict(User))
    For i = 1 To dict(User)
        Row = WorksheetFunction.Match(User, UserArray, 0)
        UserIndex(i) = Row
        UserArray(Row) = Empty
    Next
    For i = LBound(UserIndex) To UBound(UserIndex)
        Debug.Print User, UserIndex(i)
    Next
Next

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
Debug.Print "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds"
```

I could probably build a block-based index based on source (every imported file +-10.000 entries has a start- and endrow) and speed it up by looking only in the appropriate block. But maybe there is another way?

Comment: Are you committed to using Excel? If you dumped the data into Access, you could easily/quickly run some SQL to return duplicates.

Comment: Excel VBA is all I have for now. It's the final step in a long and complex piece of code.

Comment: Worksheets aren't made for this, you want an actual database. Also `Application.Transpose` has limitations: this solution won't scale. One thing you could do is in the first loop, to iterate `Range(...).Value` with a `For` loop instead of working with a `Range` and pulling `Range.Value` twice for each cell in the source range: you'll be accessing the worksheet *once* for the whole source data, rather than once for each individual cell in `UserRange`. Note that you have a number of implicit ActiveSheet references in there, likely to cause problems later.

Comment: If instead of using debug.print you wrote the whole thing to a text file at the end or something like that you could shave off a bit of time. dumping 20k+ to the immediate window seems unnecessary. The redim inside a loop probably isn't helping either.

Comment: The dictionary builds in 0.42 seconds so accessing the workbook is not the bottleneck here. Debug.Print I have turned off for doing the entire thing (it's only there for when I don't loop). It's really the looping and match/index that's taking it's time.

Comment: What's the problem with a Transpose? If I leave it out I end up with a (1 to 55000, 1 to 1) array which gives me problems. Could of course use my own loop to transpose.

Comment: Could you possibly just query your excel sheet with SQL? It may be the fastest option to get a `RecordSet` and work with it.

Comment: Too be honest I have no knowledge on this subject. Will have to look into it. However, the sole intention of this proces is input and output by Excel.

Comment: Do you use Excel for Windows? If so, you can run SQL directly on your Excel sheets. Please show sample data (redact as needed or use mock-up). Data + Code = [mcve].

Comment: See my example code below - if you make a temporary copy of the column on the worksheet then your match against that column will be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different approach which is fairly fast:

```
Sub Lister()

    Dim t, i, m, arr, rng, dict As Object, dictDupes As Object, usr, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set dictDupes = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set rng = Range("A1:A500000")
    'create some dummy data (0.5M rows)
    With rng
        .Formula = "=""USER_"" & ROUND(RAND()*5000,0) & ""_"" & ROUND(RAND()*3000,0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    t = Timer

    arr = rng.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        usr = arr(i, 1)
        If Not dict.exists(usr) Then
            dict.Add usr, i
        Else
            If Not dictDupes.exists(usr) Then dictDupes.Add usr, dict(usr)
            dictDupes(usr) = dictDupes(usr) & "|" & i
        End If
    Next i

    For Each usr In dictDupes
        v = dictDupes(usr)
        'Debug.Print "----" & usr & "---"
        'Debug.Print Join(Split(v, "|"), ", ")
    Next usr

    Debug.Print dict.Count, dictDupes.Count
    Debug.Print "Done in", Timer - t

End Sub
```

Completes in about 20-25 sec

Another note:

If you want to use Match then it's significantly faster to leave your data on the worksheet instead of running Match against an array.

```
Sub TestMatch()

    Dim t, i, m, arr, rng

    Set rng = Range("A1:A50000")
    With rng
        .Formula = "=ROUND(RAND()*30000,0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To 10000
        m = Application.Match(i, rng, 0)
    Next i
    Debug.Print "sheet", Timer - t

    arr = rng.Value
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To 10000
        arr = rng.Value
        m = Application.Match(i, arr, 0)
    Next i
    Debug.Print "array", Timer - t

End Sub
```

Output:

```
sheet          3.644531 
array          131.9453
```

So the array is about **35x slower**.

Comment: Interesting find Tim. I put my users in UserRange and completed the match in 23 sec vs 200 sec with a UserArray. It seems now the real bottleneck is the 2nd loop within my loop. Will need to do more testing.

Comment: It's the Worksheet.Index that's taking forever. I'll try and figure out a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim I got a solution going:

```
Dim dict As Dictionary
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set UserRange = Range(Cells(2, 11), Cells(LastRow, 11))
For Each cell In UserRange
    dict(cell.value) = dict(cell.value) + 1
Next

Debug.Print "Number of users: " & dict.Count

t = Timer

For Each User In dict
    Set Profile = New UserProfile
    Profile.Count = dict(User)
    Dim UserIndex() As Variant
    ReDim UserIndex(1 To dict(User))
    For i = 1 To dict(User)
        Row = WorksheetFunction.Match(User, UserRange, 0)
        UserIndex(i) = Row
    Next
    For i = LBound(UserIndex) To UBound(UserIndex)
        Dim Purchase() As Variant
        ReDim Purchase(1 To LastCol) As Variant
        Purchase = Range(Cells(UserIndex(i) + 1, 1), Cells(UserIndex(i) + 1, LastCol))
        Profile.Add Purchase
    Next
Next

Debug.Print "Match/Index loop completed in ", Timer - t
```

Turns out that matching on a range instead of an array is much faster. And so is reading from a range instead of performing an WorksheetFunction.Index on an array. These results were both unexpected to me, as I thought reading/writing to the workbook generally slows things down. I also added a **(1 ,** to thePurchase array readouts in my UserProfile class in order to ditch the Transpose.

Profiling for the whole 55K dataset completed in only 23 seconds!

Comment: I think Match/Index are optimized to perform against data on worksheets (since that's where they're typically used).  It's convenient to use them against arrays, but relative performance is quite bad when doing that. Typically you're not operating on so much data though, so it's not noticeable.